# How to change the font color of an array content with VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, fonts, colors, range

Here is a simplified version of the macro. Basically I'm just trying to change the font color of all the ranges included in my array. At "GreyArea().Select, I'm getting an error: Invalid qualifier.

```
Sub Color()
Dim GreyArea() As Variant

    GreyArea = Sheets("A").Range("D2:F500,G2:N1000")

    GreyArea().Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = 8421504
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

thats because you are declaring an array variable instead "Range" variable.

this should work for you.

```
Sub Color()
    Sheets("A").Range("D2:F500,G2:N1000").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .Color = 8421504
    End With
End Sub
```

or simply

```
Sheets("A").Range("D2:F500,G2:N1000").Font.Color = 8421504
```

Comment: Actually this is what I'm using now, it works but it does freeze excel so I thought I should use an array instead of a "Range". Usually arrays are much more efficient right?

Comment: @Seva It should not freeze your excel. try disabling the visual feedbacks by
application.ScreenUpdating = False

Comment: You're right, disabling the visual feedback did the job. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do know you could easily not select anything and literally just go:

```
Sub Color()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("D2:F5000,G2:N1000").Font.Color = 8421504

End Sub
```